# Django REST API framework without models

Tags: python, django

I created a simple html page which allows me to upload an image and store it in the directory without the use of a model. My aim is to use the REST API framework and display that particular image uploaded in the REST API i.e

```
{"image": "uploaded_image_by_user"}
```

How can I create the POST and GET methods for this REST API?

I tried doing it like this but it's not working properly. Is there a proper way to do it? Or rather, does anyone know a basic way of creating a REST API without models? FYI, I'm new to Django

My current code:

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.db import models
from django.views.generic import View, TemplateView, CreateView
from image_app.forms import ImageForm
from django.contrib.messages.views import SuccessMessageMixin
import requests
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from image_app.serializers import ImageSerializer
from django.http import Http404
import os, sys
from rest_framework.parsers import FileUploadParser
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import messages


class BaseView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "base.html"

def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        filename = rename()
        uploaded_file = request.FILES['image']
        fs = FileSystemStorage(location=settings.PRIVATE_STORAGE_ROOT)
        name = fs.save(uploaded_file.name, uploaded_file)
        messages.success(request, 'Uploaded Image Successfully.')
        return HttpResponseRedirect("base.html")
    return render(request, "insert_image.html")

class ImageList(APIView):

    def get(self, request, format = None):
        file = os.listdir(r'path_name_of_uploaded_image')[0]
        print(file)
        if file:
            images = [{"similar_image": file}]
            serializer = ImageSerializer(images, many = True).data
            return Response({'serializer': serializer}, status = status.HTTP_201_CREATED) 
        else:
            return Response({"similar_image": "Similar images are non existent"}, status = 400)

    def post(self, request):
        parser_classes = (FileUploadParser,)
        file = request.data.get('image', None)
        return Response({"similar_image": file}, status = 200)
```

**serializer.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class ImageSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    similar_image = serializers.CharField()
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason on not wanting to use a model?

Comment: Yes, all my records are in my csv file but are too large to import into Django table. Also, I was curious to see the functionalities of REST API and how much I can experiment it with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ViewSets` and override it's get and post methods
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/

in the `urls.py` provide this `SomeViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list', 'post':'create'})`

where get and posts refers to the GET and POST methods, while list and create refers to the functions in your ViewSet

You don't have to mention models anywhere.

In the end you can have something like this `return JsonResponse({"image": "uploaded_image_by_user"})`

JsonResponse as `from django.http import JsonResponse`